# difference between caeser cipher and a simple substitution cipher

Tags: cryptography, encryption

I am very confused: I have been browsing through the Internet, searched some blogs etc, but I'm really getting confused.  My question is about a `Caesar cipher` and a `simple substitution cipher` -- is there any difference? Some blogs when I search `simple substitution cipher` I get `Caesar cipher`.  Is there anyone who can explain to me if they are the same or not? I really want to make a program that will work as a `simple substitution cipher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Caesar cipher uses a simple shift to determine the encrypted text. This example is taken from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

If you use a left shift of 3, you get a cipher that looks like

```
Plain:    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Cipher:   XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
```

So, any X in the encrypted string would be an A when decrypted, Y is B, etc.

A substitution cipher is a more generic form where instances of one value are always replaced with instances of another value. For example, all X's are replaced with Q's.

The Caesar cipher is a specific type of substitution cipher, but not all substitution ciphers are Caesar ciphers.

Answer (score 2):

The term "Caesar cipher" is usually used for rotation ciphers (most commonly for -3, ie D->A, E->B, ... as this is the one that Caesar apparently used as far as I'm aware).

A simple substitution cipher doesn't have to be a rotation, but could substitute any letter by any other, e.g. A->G, B->Z, C->D, E->W, ...

There are only 26 rotation ciphers (the trivial one not really being an encryption method), while there are 26! substitution ciphers in general, some of them keeping one or multiple letters the same.

Answer (score 1):

A Caesar Cipher is

> a type of substitution cipher in which each letter in the plaintext is replaced by a letter some fixed number of positions down the alphabet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

In other words, a Caesar Cipher is a simple special case of a substitution cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Caeser Cipher:  It’s essential a simplified substitution Cipher, that shifts each 
letter in the alphabet 3 characters A>D, B>E etc. 
for Example:

Message =   A B C E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

```
         we will count 3 letters after M.   NOP so M > P
```

Answer (score 0):

plain text: **A B C D E F G H I J K L**

Cipher    : **X Y Z A B C D E F G H I**

*So in Caesar Cipher we use left shift of 3, so that after encryption **'A'** will be **'X'**.*

Comment: This is exactly what the accepted answer tells you. Do not repeat answers, upvote.